# how to give the user to execute all procedures under the db (regular methods doesn't works)?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, privileges

I have a db and there are a few procedures, what I need to do is create a user and give him certain permissions for use including usage of procedures.

What I do for it is

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'user_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT CREATE, DROP, DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON mydb.* TO 'user'@'user_ip';
GRANT EXECUTE ON mydb.* TO 'user'@'user_ip';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

then when I open the db with this user I see tables, but I don't see procedures...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *but I don't see procedures...* What do you mean by "see"? You receive some error message while trying to call a procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created below Procedure with root user

```
 DELIMITER //
 
 CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllTitles() BEGIN  SELECT *  FROM titles; END //
 
 DELIMITER ;
```

Then gave the proper permission as you mentioned

```
 CREATE USER 'my_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Not_so_secure!1'; GRANT
 CREATE, DROP, DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON employees.* TO
 'my_user'@'%'; GRANT EXECUTE ON employees.* TO 'my_user'@'%'; FLUSH
 PRIVILEGES;
```

Then connected with that user my_user

```
       mysql> select user();
      +-------------------+ 
      | user()            |
      +-------------------+ 
      | my_user@localhost |
      +-------------------+ 
      1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then check the if I can see the procedure with below command connected to mysql using my_user

```
 mysql> SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS \G;
 *************************** 1. row ***************************
                   Db: employees
                 Name: GetAllTitles
                 Type: PROCEDURE
              Definer: root@localhost
             Modified: 2021-05-17 12:55:05
             Created: 2021-05-17 12:55:05
       Security_type: DEFINER
              Comment:  character_set_client: latin1 collation_connection: latin1_swedish_ci   Database Collation:
 latin1_swedish_ci 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then tried to call it's working

```
 CALL employees.GetAllTitles();
```

Make sure you are flushing the privileges

Answer (score -4):

To grant permissions on a stored procedure

1.In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of Database Engine and then expand that instance.

2.Expand Databases, expand the database in which the procedure belongs, and then expand Programmability.

3.Expand Stored Procedures, right-click the procedure to grant permissions on, and then click Properties.

4.From Stored Procedure Properties, select the Permissions page.

5.To grant permissions to a user, database role, or application role, click Search.

6.In Select Users or Roles, click Object Types to add or clear the users and roles you want.

7.Click Browse to display the list of users or roles. Select the users or roles to whom permissions should be granted.

8.In the Explicit Permissions grid, select the permissions to grant to the specified user or role. For a description of the permissions, see Permissions (Database Engine).

Please follow [Microsoft Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/grant-permissions-on-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Using%20SQL%20Server%20Management%20Studio,-To%20grant%20permissions&text=Expand%20Stored%20Procedures%2C%20right%2Dclick,or%20application%20role%2C%20click%20Search.) to get better solution.

Comment: Not applicable to MySQL.